# SAPUI5:Sending odata requests in a loop while there is returned nested data

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm a bit stuck on finding an efficient solution for a requirement which is as follows:
From the valueHelp user has selected one id, now using this id, we have to get all the nested information from unknown number or levels

```
    {Id: '1234',
     nestedInfo: [
       {id: "45",nestedInfo:[{}]},
       {id: "65",
        nestedInfo:[
           {id: "479",nestedInfo:[{}]}]}]}
```

So all I have initially is `'1234'` for which I'm sending odata request to get that first level of nestedInfo, then I need to loop through `nestedInfo` and send requests for each Id those to get their `nestedInfo`, and so on and so forth... Obviously I can't use `($expand=nestedInfo($expand=nestedInfo))` as those levels could be too many for server to handle at once, and also I have no idea at the beginning how many of those I should add.

So I'm looking for an efficient solution how to handle all these requests, while there is data in the nestedInfo array from the request.

Thanks for insights,
Shanir

Comment: Odata 2 & 4 can do expands so you can fetch a bigger part of the tree with one request. 

If the data is not to deep - simply request always the max level.